# TestNG: How to run classes in serial and Tests in Parallel?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, parallel-testing

I have a testng.xml like below,

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="MyTestSuite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.example.FBOneClass" />
            <class name="com.example.FBTwoClass" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test2">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.example.GOneClass" />
            <class name="com.example.GTwoClass" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Here, I'm trying to achieve the tests to run in parallel. I can do that by the `parallel="tests" thread-count="2"`

But the class should run serially! Like all the methods in the `com.example.FBOneClass`  should execute first and then `com.example.FBTwoClass` methods should run.

What I'm facing is, some of the @Test methods in `com.example.FBTwoClass`  are getting executed before `com.example.FBOneClass` @Test methods.

How to achieve the expected behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Note: I did research on it. We can achieve it using the "dependsOn" parameter. But I can't use the `com.example.FBTwoClass` first method depends on `com.example.FBOneClass` last method!

Comment: Tests should be independed. So the order is not importent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `parallel="false"` in your `<test>` tag of your suite file. This will ensure that the `<test>` tags are executed in parallel, but the individual test classes within the `<test>` tag will run sequentially.

Note: Also please ensure that you are using the latest released version of TestNG viz.,

- `7.5.1` - If you are using JDK8
- `7.8.0` - If you are using JDK11

Answer (score 0):

A relevant issue is faced in the order of methods execution between devices for parallel automation.
https://github.com/AppiumTestDistribution/appium-device-farm/issues/780